# I am getting a 200 response in postman when I try to update a field which is not in the Schema and it doesn't showing any error

Tags: node.js, postman, mern

[image]

this is my postman where I am this

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mongoose and you want an error to be thrown when you try to save properties that are not specified in the schema, you can set the `strict` [schema setting](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) to `'throw'`.

```js
const mySchema = new Schema(
  {
    myField1: String,
    myField2: Number,
  },
  { strict: 'throw' },
);
```